# Как взять значение выбранной даты из календаря?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Доброго времени суток друзья! есть такой Input даты ( календарь)

```
<input type="date" class="datepicker-here" value="" id="datep">
```

И такой DIV

```
<div class="time">Дата Уборки: </div>
```

Хочу чтобы при выборе тоесть при нажатии на какое-то число из календаря, выводило его в div с классом .time

Comment: Мало информации. Добавьте сюда воспроизводимый пример кода через вставку кода. С стилями, дейтпикером и тем что вы пробовали сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю как-то вот так:

```js
document.querySelector('.datepicker-here').addEventListener('change', (e) =>
{
  document.querySelector('.time span').innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="date" class="datepicker-here" value="" id="datep"><br><br>
<div class="time">Дата Уборки: <span></span></div>
```